# why does a web audio oscillator only play a note once?

Tags: javascript, webkit, web-audio-api

When I successfully create a tone with a Web Audio oscillator (with `noteOn`), then call its `noteOff` function, subsequent calls to `noteOn` doesn't play the tone again. I seem to have to create a new oscillator to play a new note. Why is this?

```
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext();
var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
osc.connect(ctx.destination);
osc.start(0); // tone is heard (previously noteOn(0))

// ... some time later
osc.stop(0); // tone falls silent (previously noteOff(0))

// ... some time later
osc.start(0); // no effect! (previously noteOn(0))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply put - the API is designed that way, and optimised for that kind of use. One doesn't have much choice except creating a new oscillator per note.

Comment: This answer is confirmed by the faq here:
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ

Answer (score 6):

<s>Use an oscillator pool and control note on/off with a gain node.  Like analog synths, the oscillators are running all the time in the pool.</s>

While it can work to create an oscillator pool, the Web Audio API has been so optimized that it's not worth doing.  I previously thought an oscillator pool was a good idea, but it's not.  It's quite simple to create a new oscillator every time you need a new note -- much simpler than maintaining a pool -- and there is no significant hit to performance caused by this continual create/garbage-collect process.

And if you think about it, this is a very clean programming model.  No need to maintain references to objects and then reuse them later.  Less state to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'll probably do this. Care to comment on why the API was designed this way (where noteOff effectively destroys the oscillator)?

Comment: noteOn/noteOff is a terrible name if this is really the intended behaviour :(

Comment: yes noteOn and noteOff have been deprecated and will be replace with start / stop.

Comment: @fisherwebdev Could you please elaborate on that start/stop comment, perhaps with a url?

Comment: Or teach a man to fish:
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#deprecation-section

Comment: With a sampler and especially a game with sound effects, the HTML5 Rocks FAQ is correct: "The idea of this architecture is to decouple audio asset from playback state. Taking a record player analogy, buffers are analogous to records and sources to play-heads. Because many applications involve multiple versions of the same buffer playing simultaneously, this pattern is essential."  I'll have to think a bit about how and why a pool of oscillators might be better or worse for a polyphonic synth, however.  Could be some good reasons to create/destroy them, like creating wavetables on the fly.

Comment: Yeah, for buffers that makes a great deal of sense. In the case of oscillators though, it's common to want to turn them off and on again some number of times (sometimes a lot!). This can be achieved by placing the oscillators behind a gain node, which is the "best practice" I think, but that means that the oscillator is constantly running in the background (using resources) without contributing to the overall sound. Depending on the "note pruning" strategy, this could cause other, new oscillators not to play, or for these "dormant" ones to be destroyed... (whoops! rant!)

Answer (score 5):

What about changing the frequency to 0? It seems to work in this [Dataflow + Web Audio API](http://forresto.github.com/dataflow-webaudio/) sandbox. (`start` and `stop` use the disconnect / reconnect pattern.)

Comment: Hrm... Not a bad idea. Good solution, thanks! If the question wasn't more about the "why", I'd accept this!

Comment: Playing with it more, if you are scheduling notes from a sequencer and want accurate timing with the web audio clock you'll have to make a new oscillator for every note.

Comment: Really? I thought frequency could be set with sample-accurate timing?

Comment: You're right, with `setValueAtTime` ... mono synths ahoy! https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#methodsandparams-AudioParam

Comment: the problem with this method is you will not be able to reset the phase of the oscillator since it will be running. This is an issue for musical applications.

Comment: @forresto *"mono synths ahoy!"* -- not necessarily, you could allocate a pool of oscillators for polyphonic sounds.